# jquery click triggered by underlaying div

Tags: jquery, click

I'm making a lightbox of my own.

I have a semi transparent div that is fixed over the whole screen and inside it I have the lightbox centered with my content. A div in a div.

I'm not that great with jQ so I don't know how to make sure that the click event (to close container with dimmed div and lightbox) ONLY is triggered when clicking the dimmed area and not if I click something in the lightbox.

In essence: to close down the popup and semi transparent area if clicking on the semi transparent area, BUT NOT IF I CLICK IN THE MIDDLE LIGHTBOX.

This is what I got so far:
( with lightbox centered like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8620628/891052 )

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#openpopup").click(function() {
 $('#closepopup').toggle();
  });
  $("#closepopup").click(function() {
 $('#closepopup').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {height:100%;}
#closepopup {
 background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 
 THIS_CENTERS_CONTENT:;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align:center;
}
.fullheight { 
 THIS_CENTERS_CONTENT:;
 height:100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 display: inline-block;
}

#popupbox {
 background:#ebebeb;
 border-radius:15px;
 text-align:left;
 height:auto;
 
 THIS_CENTERS_CONTENT:;
 max-width:90%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 display: inline-block;
}
#popupboxinner {
 THIS_KEEPS_CONTENT_PLACED:;
 max-width:800px; SAME_AS_MAX_IMG_WIDTH:;
 padding:20px 30px;
 min-width:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="closepopup">
 <span class="fullheight"></span>
 <div id="popupbox">
  <div id="popupboxinner">
   LIGHTBOX CONTENT - SHOULD NOT CLOSE IF CLICKED
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<span id="openpopup">OPEN CLICKABLE SEMI TRANSPARENT WRAPPER WITH LIGHTBOX INSIDE</span>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237516/jquery-click-outside-div-to-hide-a-div
But that has your answer: put a click handler on the transparent div :)

Comment: that's what I did. I put a click handler on the semi transparent div, but it gets triggered as well when I click the lightbox area div inside it, something I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#openpopup").click(function() {
 $('#closepopup').toggle();
  });
  $("#closepopup").click(function() {
 $('#closepopup').toggle();
  });
  $('#popupbox').click(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {height:100%;}
#closepopup {
 background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 
 THIS_CENTERS_CONTENT:;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align:center;
}
.fullheight { 
 THIS_CENTERS_CONTENT:;
 height:100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 display: inline-block;
}

#popupbox {
 background:#ebebeb;
 border-radius:15px;
 text-align:left;
 height:auto;
 
 THIS_CENTERS_CONTENT:;
 max-width:90%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 display: inline-block;
}
#popupboxinner {
 THIS_KEEPS_CONTENT_PLACED:;
 max-width:800px; SAME_AS_MAX_IMG_WIDTH:;
 padding:20px 30px;
 min-width:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="closepopup">
 <span class="fullheight"></span>
 <div id="popupbox">
  <div id="popupboxinner">
   LIGHTBOX CONTENT
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<span id="openpopup">OPEN</span>
```

Comment: thank you. this works, although something else must prevent it on the site I'm working on.

Comment: ah, found it! In your previous example (that I used) you had missed adding a curly bracket on the end. please fix for others to not bang their head ;)

Comment: Ah, fixed. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Did a quick markup for you on an example lightbox! Basically, as Noah said, you just put a click event on the transparent div.

Let me know if you have issues following the code!

```js
$('#lightbox-wrapper').click(function() {
  $('#lightbox-wrapper, #lightbox').toggleClass('open');
});


function openLightBox() {
  $('#lightbox-wrapper, #lightbox').toggleClass('open');
}
```

```css
/* DEFAULT STATE */

#lightbox-wrapper {
  display: none;
}
#lightbox {
  display: none;
}
#lightbox-wrapper.open {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
#lightbox.open {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 40vh;
}
#lightbox-content {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lightbox-wrapper"></div>
<div id="lightbox">
  <div id="lightbox-content">
    <h1>I'm a lightbox</h1>
  </div>
</div>


<button onclick="javascript:openLightBox()">Open Lightbox</button>
```

Comment: This didnt solve my dilemma. I'm sorry I didn't explain myself better. I changed my original question as an effect.

Comment: I'm sorry, your example does not work. And I need the wrapper to contain the lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the click from propagating:

```
$('#lightbox').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Just swap out `#lightbox` for the id of your inner div (the lightbox inside the transparent div) and add this to your existing code.

// edited - added curly bracket on end. - Paul

Comment: could you please place this in it's context as a working example?

Comment: You can add this to your working code, or Schultzie's code below.

Comment: I tried adding it to both my own version and Schultzie's version, with result that a click does nothing. I would be very grateful if you could show me a working example.

Comment: Sorry @Paul! I thought that's what you wanted: click on the lightbox to do nothing, click outside the lightbox to close the lightbox?

Comment: problem is that clicking outside the lightbox does nothing.

Comment: I added my code above, if you kindly could edit it so it works?

Comment: Done - added a new answer :)